# MongoDB Nested RunCommand

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, nosql

I have a collection called "stops" that stores some coordinate info. I used MongoDB 2dsphere index for searching places. For example, I want to query all the stops around a certain position using `db.runCommand`:

`db.runCommand({
    geoNear: "stops",
    near: { type: "Point" , coordinates: [ -123.115115, 49.209659 ] },
    spherical: true,
    minDistance: 0,
    maxDistance: 200,
    })`

The result is an json array:

`{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "dis" : 79.0147493688595,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57e2349b9d0263463a3e93aa"),
                "zone_id" : "ZN 99",
                "coordinate" : [ 
                    -123.116116, 
                    49.209383
                ],
                "stop_id" : 11252,
                "stop_code" : 61338,
                "stop_url" : "",
                "stop_desc" : "MARINE DRIVE STATION LOOP @ BAY 2",
                "stop_name" : "MARINE DRIVE STN BAY 2",
                "location_type" : 0,
                "parent_station" : ""
            }
        },
            {
            "dis" : 140.73823410181,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57e2349b9d0263463a3eaec9"),
                "zone_id" : "ZN 1",
                "coordinate" : [ 
                    -123.117038, 
                    49.209801
                ],
                "stop_id" : 11286,
                "stop_code" : "",
                "stop_url" : "",
                "stop_desc" : "SKYTRAIN @ MARINE DRIVE STN",
                "stop_name" : "MARINE DRIVE STATION",
                "location_type" : 0,
                "parent_station" : ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "nscanned" : 14,
        "objectsLoaded" : 2,
        "avgDistance" : 123.782109714949,
        "maxDistance" : 140.73823410181,
        "time" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}`

**I am wondering can we do a nested runCommand to further filter the result to be like**

`{"results" : [ 
        {
            "dis" : 79.0147493688595,
            "obj" : {
                "coordinate" : [ 
                    -123.116116, 
                    49.209383
                ],
                "stop_id" : 11252,
                "stop_code" : 61338,
                "stop_desc" : "MARINE DRIVE STATION LOOP @ BAY 2",
                "stop_name" : "MARINE DRIVE STN BAY 2",
            }
        },
            {
            "dis" : 140.73823410181,
            "obj" : {
                "coordinate" : [ 
                    -123.117038, 
                    49.209801
                ],
                "stop_id" : 11286,
                "stop_code" : "",
                "stop_desc" : "SKYTRAIN @ MARINE DRIVE STN",
                "stop_name" : "MARINE DRIVE STATION",
            }
        }
    ]
}`

There is a lot of useless info in original json response.

Comment: Instead of `runCommand` start trying with `aggregate`, like: db.stops.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-123.115115, 49.209659] },
        spherical: true,
        minDistance: 0,
        maxDistance: 200,
    }
}])

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy Thanks! I've tried that. And returning:`"errmsg" : "$geoNear requires a 'distanceField' option as a String",` I think the value after geoNear has to be a collection name

Comment: Yes, in that case it needs the `distanceField`. Take a look here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy Thanks! That works!

Comment: Good! I will turn this into a answer, so we can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aggregate` instead of `runCommand`. It would be like:

```
db.stops.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-123.115115, 49.209659] },
        spherical: true,
        minDistance: 0,
        maxDistance: 200,
        distanceField: 'someDistanceFieldProperty'
    }
}]);
```

Take a look at the docs for you to go further: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/